# Can you kill all non-quest NPC's permanently

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'd like to start recording some Fallout NV, in which I'd naturally discover each location and murder that locations population.

So if I was to do this, if I returned to the locations which I discovered, would the non-quest NPC's still be dead or would they respawn.

Comment: The rather excellent Many A True Nerd on Youtube did a play through of NV wherein he killed everyone it was possible to kill. Check it out [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwH1xJhcXG0eO7X0ibAb03F8U91KDdCLO) if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named NPCs don't respawn. "Generic" ones will (ie Fiend, NCR Trooper, etc).